# How to (cross-)compile boost WITHOUT python?

Tags: python, boost, cross-compiling

I have a gcc 4.3.3 toolchain for my embedded device but I have no python (and don't need it).

I'am looking for a way to configure boostbuild without python (compilation and cross-compilation).

Is python mandatory ?

Must I compile every single parts but boost-python ? (I hope not).

Thanks in advance.

**What I did thanks to Jupiter**

```
./bootstrap.sh --without-libraries=python
./b2
```

and I got

```
Component configuration:

    - chrono                   : building
    - context                  : building
    - date_time                : building
    - exception                : building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : building
    - graph_parallel           : building
    - iostreams                : building
    - locale                   : building
    - math                     : building
    - mpi                      : building
    - program_options          : building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : building
    - signals                  : building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : building
    - thread                   : building
    - timer                    : building
    - wave                     : building
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look at --without-* bjam option e.g. --without-python

Comment: This answer is way too terse. Where do you set this option?

Comment: You run `./boostrap.sh` to configure, and `./b2` to build. This step applies in the build step, i.e. `./b2  --without-python`.